# How to retrieve value from firebase without getting the unique key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve an url from Firebase in Android. However, my problem is that I can't retrieve the url without also getting the unique key of the child.

The value I am trying to retrieve is the following:

[image: Firebase Image]

Down below is the code I use to retrieve the data from firebase.

```
 final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference().child("LoadItems");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                String key;
                key = child.getKey();

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + key);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + child.getValue());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
```

So what I am trying to get is what the url alone.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't add your code as an image <https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to know any key in order to get that URL. So please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference shoesRef = rootRef.child("LoadItems").child("Shoes");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String url = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
shoesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```